# jQuery UI Dialog cause page jump on open & close on ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, page-jump

I have an ASP.NET C# page, with image thumbnails in it.
I created a script that opens a `jQuery UI Dialog` on each hover on a thumbnail that shows me the thumbnail in larger size in a dialog view, and when I hover out - dialog closes.
My little annoying problem is, that in every `mouseover` (trigger dialog to open) - the page makes itself 'longer' - a scrollbar appears on the side of the browser, and it seems like the page gets longer when a dialog is openning, but it shouldn't do so.
When I hover off (`mouseout`) - the dialog disappears and the page returns to its normal state.
Because of this- when I hover through the thumbnails, my page 'jumps'.
I looked for a solution for this, and I've added `return false;` for each dialog open, and close - and it still doesn't make any different.
Sorry for the unperfect english, and thanks for all helpers!

Comment: I've had the same issue but hadn't gotten around to research and tackle the problem.  My guess is that it could possibly be solved with a style change but, again, I haven't taken time to follow through on that idea.  I'm eager to read answers to your question.

Answer (score 3):

I finally got my solution - for all interested:

```
open: function(event, ui){  
   /*  
    * Scrollbar fix   
    */  
   $('body').css('overflow','hidden');  
}
```

I added this to dialog's opening event and it fixed the issue!

Comment: This totally worked for me as well.  Thanks for posting your solution.